# Second Order Non-Homogenous O.D.E

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I understand that the below is a non-homogeneous second order O.D.E.

$y'' + 4y = sin^2(x)$

and that I can re-arrange the R.H.S to get

$y'' + 4y = \frac{1}{2}(1 - cos2x)$

However, may I know how to proceed from here on?

Thank you.

Comment: First, solve $y''+4y=0$

Comment: what have you got for the solution of the homogeneous solution?

Comment: @JJacquelin I got $y = Acos2x + Bsin2x$ for that equation.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Hi, as above my solution is $y = Acos2x + Bsin2x$.

Comment: for $$y_P$$ make the ansatz $$y_p=A+B\cos(2x)+Cx\sin(2x)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I understand that $y(x) = y_{h}(x) + y_{p}(x)$ and that $y_{p}(x)$ is a solution of $y'' + 4y = sin^2(x)$ without arbitrary constant.  However, I am lost at what to do with the ansatz. Could you explain to me how you derived at the ansatz and what's my next course of action so that I can add $y_{h}$ and $y_{p}$ eventually?

Comment: you must this plug in your equation to determine the constants $$A,B,C$$

Comment: @stephchia: I think it will be of great help for you to read/review http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the substantial way of doing it
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y+4y=\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{d}{dx}y+2iy\Big)-2i\Big(\frac{d}{dx}y+2iy\Big)$$
Let
$$\xi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}y+2iy$$
Then
$$\frac{d}{dx}\xi-2i\xi=\sin^{2}(x)$$
Using the integrating factor thing you have
$$\xi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}y+2iy=e^{2ix}\Big\{\int_{0}^{x}\sin^{2}(z)e^{-2iz}dz+\xi_{0}\Big\}$$
Using the integrating factor the second time you get
$$y(x)=e^{-2ix}\Big\{\int_{0}^{x}e^{4iw}\Big\{\int_{0}^{w}\sin^{2}(z)e^{-2iz}dz+\xi_{0}\Big\}dw+x_{0}\Big\}$$
Then do the integrals)